# How to update title on web page Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, wifi, html

Now I have a problem with my Arduino web page. I would do that the title updates every 5 seconds.

My problem is that this code sents the data  to web page 1 time and its works fine but the other messages will not sented.

My code now is

```
statusCode = 200;
content = "Nice to see you whats is your name?";
server.send(statusCode, "application/json", content);

delay(5000);
content = "Hello, How are you?";

server.send(statusCode, "application/json", content);
```

Please can somebody show me how to get this to sent to the website again after five seconds.

```
server.send(statusCode, "application/json", "Hi");
delay(1000);
server.send(statusCode, "application/json", "Hello");
delay(1000);
```

why this not works?

Comment: I think your connection is closed by the server. to send the reminder data you need to connect your arduino with the server again.

Answer (score 0):

The server.send closes the connection with the requesting system.

To achieve what you are trying to achieve, you will have to do the following.
1) Make a javascript page, which can connect to a TCP server.
2) The javascript page should listen to the TCP server for updates, and should put these updates on the browser.
3) Use WiFiServer on your (I am guessing esp8266) Arduino, to start a server to which the javascript will connect to. 
http://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/server-examples.html
4) Embed the javascript into your Arduino code, so that the full javascript file is sent as a response to a web query.
5) At the end of the delay, send the updated data via the WiFiServer object.

This is a based on how most dynamic web-pages that I know work. 
I have not tested this, but in my opinion this should work.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help.